# Large initial displacements/angles on a pendulum

Tags: angle

Why does large initial displacements/angles on a pendulum affect the period and the accuracy of oscillation? I know at small angles it does not effect the period however large angles (maybe above 30$^o$) do..

Thank you

Comment: Intuitively, imagine if you gave a pendulum enough momentum that it would flip almost all the way over. Then it would hang for a very long time nearly balanced upside-down before swinging back. By giving it closer to that perfect amount of momentum so that it gets to the top and rests perfectly upside-down, the period can be made arbitrarily long. So the period must be amplitude-dependent. As Ross's answer shows, the harmonic approximation (which implies that the oscillation frequency doesn't depend on initial conditions) breaks down when the amplitude gets too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the derivation of the equation of motion, there is an approximation made that $\sin \theta = \theta$.  Before the approximation the equation is $\ddot \theta + \frac gl \sin \theta =0$.  Once you make the approximation you have a simple harmonic oscillator.  As the Taylor series of $\sin \theta$ around zero is $\sin \theta \approx \theta - \frac 16 \theta^2 $ we are ignoring the cubic (and higher) term(s).  This is valid when the angle is small.

Comment: Ah okay cheers! so sin θ ≈ θ up to about 0.244 radians (14°) due to the small angle approximation with the taylor series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation
Thanks for the understanding

Comment: There is no specific value for which the approximation breaks down.  It is a function of how accurate you want to be.